# Finding the normalizing constants for the following orthogonal set

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, fourier-series

let $\phi_n=(e^{inx})$ for $integer \ n$ I have verified that each elements of this set is orthogonal to eachother on $[0,2\pi]$ But while trying to normalize I ended up with the following problem:

To normalize I need to have $||\phi_n||=1$ for each $integer$ $n$

Set :, so we can find the constant $\alpha$
$$||\phi_n||^2 = <\phi_n,\phi_n> = \alpha\int_0^{2\pi}e^{2inx}dx=1$$

Solving we end up with :

$$\alpha\frac{e^{4\pi in}-1}{2in}=1$$ I can't solve for $\alpha$ here since $$e^{4\pi in}=1$$ by euler's idendity. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take a complex conjugate of the first function when you take the inner product

$$||\phi_n||^2 = <\phi_n,\phi_n> = \alpha\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-inx}e^{inx}dx=\alpha \int_0^{2\pi}dx=1$$
which will give you a way to solve for the normalization constant.

Comment: Why so? Why taking complex conjugate defines an inner product and the way I did doesnt?

Comment: @Xenidia this is the standard way of defining the inner product for complex functions.